# Windows 2008 r2 server core with WSUS role installed possible?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, wsus, windows-server-core

Is it possible to install the WSUS role on a Windows 2008 R2 Server Core installation? Alternatively, is it possible to install this role on a Windows 2012 Server Core?

Answer (score 2):

Not really.  Run `oclist` to get a list of "available" (supported) roles and features for Server Core, WSUS isn't one of them.

That said, it's *mostly* possible (but I sure as hell wouldn't do it).  [Here's a link to a guide on how to force WSUS onto a Server Core 2008 R2 install](http://etechgoodness.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/installing-the-wsus-server-component-on-server-core-2008-r2/), but again, I certainly advise against it, and seeing as how you'll have to install a SQL instance on another machine (since MS SQL Server and their internal database *require* a GUI), the value of doing so seems rather questionable.

EDIT:  [Turns out that installing MS SQL Server on Server Core is possible, provided you're using MS SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231669.aspx).

Comment: You are right, i noticed that windows server 2012 core offers WSUS as a role, i ll explore that possibility.  I wonder if it is worth maintaining a server core instance just for a wsus role, thank you for your reply

Comment: I am running SQL Server 2008R2 just fine on Server Core, it does not need a GUI, neither for installation nor operation.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf ServerCore2012, or Server Core 2008R2?

Comment: @HopelessN00b - Both, you just run the installer with /q and a ConfigurationFile. I have a SQL 2008R2 running on Server 2008R2 Core for several months now, no problems.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf Interesting.  I'll have to test that out.  Nowish.  But it seems like maybe you should wrap an answer to question around that interesting tidbit... if it checks out, I'd give that an upboat, for sure (and perhaps delete my answer for incorrectness).

Comment: I haven't tried WSUS on Core, so I can't say anything about that. I don't think it's worth an answer. I just wanted to say that SQL shouldn't be the problem.