# Can I use SQL-Server on Windows Server 2008 R2 core?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, windows-server-core

Is it possible to run SQL-Server 2008R2 or 2012 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Core installation.

There are three questions to answer:

- Does the license allow this?
- Can I install and operate it?
- Is it supported by Microsoft?

This question came up on a question about [WSUS on Server Core](https://serverfault.com/questions/450745/windows-2008-r2-server-core-with-wsus-role-installed-possible/450751#comment491733_450751), other products require SQL-Server as well, so it would nice nice to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While SQL-Server 2012 has been tested and and is fully supported by Microsoft, this is not the case for SQL-Server 2008R2. However is it still possible to install and run this version of SQL-Server on Windows Server Core installations.

Here's what to do to install SQL 2008R2 on a Server 2008R2 core edition:

- install dot.NET Framework 3.51

  ```
  pkgmgr /iu:NetFx2-ServerCore;NetFx2-ServerCore-WOW64
  ocsetup ServerCore-WOW64
  ocsetup NetFx2-ServerCore
  ocsetup NetFx2-ServerCore-WOW64
  DISM /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3-ServerCore
  DISM /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3-ServerCore-WOW64
  ```
- install PowerShell

  ```
  pkgmgr /iu:MicrosoftWindowsPowerShell
  ```
- Prepare a SQL-Server setup configuration file, this example is for SQL-Express:

  ```
  ;SQLSERVER2008 Configuration File
  [SQLSERVER2008]
  INSTANCEID="MSSQLSERVER"
  INSTANCENAME="MSSQLSERVER"
  ACTION="Install"
  FEATURES=SQLENGINE,FullText
  HELP="False"
  INDICATEPROGRESS="False"
  QUIET="True"
  QUIETSIMPLE="False"

  X86="False"

  ENU="True"
  ERRORREPORTING="False"
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server"
  INSTANCEDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

  ;The Database Engine root data directory.
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR="D:\SqlData"
  ;Directory for Database Engine TempDB files.
  SQLTEMPDBDIR="D:\SqlData\SysData"
  ;Directory for the Database Engine TempDB log files.          
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR="D:\SqlData\SysLogs"           

  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
  FILESTREAMLEVEL="0"

  ENABLERANU="False"

  SQLCOLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"

  SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER"

  SAPWD = "*********"
  SECURITYMODE = "SQL"

  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="True"

  TCPENABLED="1"
  NPENABLED="0"

  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Disabled"
  SQLBACKUPDIR = "D:\Backups\Sql"
  SQLUSERDBDIR = "D:\SqlData\UserData\Data"
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR = "D:\SqlData\UserData\Logs"
  ```

For more information about the configuration file see the TechNet article: [How to: Install SQL Server 2008 Using a Configuration File](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239405%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

If you have downloaded an .exe rather than using a DVD/ISO, you have to extract the setup files first:

```
    SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe -x
```

- Run the installed in quiet mode:

  ```
  setup.exe /ACTION=Install /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /q /ConfigurationFile=C:\SQL2008ForCore.ini
  ```
- Extract the Service Pack files:

  ```
  SQLServer2008R2SP1-KB2528583-x64-ENU.exe -x
  ```

Installing the service pack from a network drive did not work for me, make sure the files are on a local disk.

- Install the service pack:

  ```
  setup.exe /quiet /allinstances /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms
  ```

You should now be able to connect to the instance from a remote SQL-Server Management Studio. You can also use sqlcmd.exe on the command line.

If you need a local GUI tool to run your queries, you can use [Query Express](http://www.albahari.com/queryexpress.aspx), a small no-install single file application that works in Server Core.

I've been using SQL 2008R2 on Server Core for about six months now. I have not tested it with heavy loads but I don't see why it would behave any different from a version  installed on a full-GUI windows.

Answer (score 0):

yes sql 2012 will install on server core either version w2k12 or 2k8.

Answer (score 0):

[Ah, it apparently depends on the version of MS SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231669.aspx).  MS SQL Server 2008, no.  MS SQL Server 2012, yes.

> Starting with SQL Server 2012, you can install SQL Server on a Server Core installation of Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 or Windows Server 2012. This topic provides setup-specific details for installing SQL Server 2012 on Server Core.